# Attributes missing in <cfdocumentItem >

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cfparam name="attributes.mytestvalue" default="0">
<cfdump var="#attributes#">

<!---  Attributes are there. --->

<cfdocumentSection>
   <cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
      <cfdump var="#attributes#">
   </cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
</cfdocumentSection>

<!---  Attributes are not there. --->
```

Why does this happen? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to \WEB-INF\cftags\META-INF\taglib.cftld, cfdocumentsection and cfdocumentitem are implemented as custom tags themselves and therefore possibly have their own attributes scope, thereby masking the values you've put into attributes scope.

You could try this:

```
<cfdocumentSection>
   <cfdocumentitem type="footer" mytestvalue="#attributes.myTestValue#> 
      <cfdump var="#attributes#">
   </cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
</cfdocumentSection>
```

Or perhaps this:

```
<cfset attribs={type="footer", myTestValue=0}>
<cfdocumentSection>
   <cfdocumentitem attributeCollection="#attribs#"> 
      <cfdump var="#attributes#">
   </cfdocumentitem> 
</cfdocumentSection>
```

Also, although I don't think it's the problem here, you've got the type="footer" attribute on the closing tag of cfdocumentItem, which isn't necessary

Comment: Sorry the type="footer" was a cut and paste error since the actual code is on a different system.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset request.myTestValue=attributes.myTestValue>

<cfdocumentSection>
   <cfdocumentitem type="footer" mytestvalue="#request.myTestValue#> 
      <cfdump var="#attributes#">
   </cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
</cfdocumentSection>
```

This fixed it However now I know why it was not working. Thanks Barnyr.